# PyTorch Lightning functools.partial error

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I'm using a combination of PyTorch Forecasting and PyTorch Lightning, and running into an odd error. Some code below.

```
batch_size = 128
train_dataloader = training.to_dataloader(train=True, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=8)
val_dataloader = validation.to_dataloader(train=False, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=8)

.
.
.

tft = TemporalFusionTransformer.from_dataset(
    training,
    learning_rate=0.05,
    hidden_size=16,  # biggest influence network size
    attention_head_size=1,
    dropout=0.1,
    hidden_continuous_size=8,
    output_size=7,  # QuantileLoss has 7 quantiles by default
    loss=QuantileLoss(),
    log_interval=10,  # log example every 10 batches
    reduce_on_plateau_patience=4,  # reduce learning automatically
)

trainer.fit(
    tft,
    train_dataloaders=train_dataloader,
    val_dataloaders=val_dataloader
)
```

However, I then run into this error and I can't figure out why. Can anyone help me figure out what to do with the below error? I tried playing around with changing the syntax for the val_dataloader, but couldn't get anything to work.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/model.py", line 136, in <module>
    val_dataloaders=val_dataloader,
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 553, in fit
    self._run(model)
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 912, in _run
    self._pre_dispatch()
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 941, in _pre_dispatch
    self._log_hyperparams()
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 970, in _log_hyperparams
    self.logger.save()
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\utilities\distributed.py", line 48, in wrapped_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\loggers\tensorboard.py", line 249, in save
    save_hparams_to_yaml(hparams_file, self.hparams)
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\core\saving.py", line 405, in save_hparams_to_yaml
    yaml.dump(v)
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\yaml\__init__.py", line 290, in dump
    return dump_all([data], stream, Dumper=Dumper, **kwds)
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\yaml\__init__.py", line 278, in dump_all
    dumper.represent(data)
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 27, in represent
    node = self.represent_data(data)
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 52, in represent_data
    node = self.yaml_multi_representers[data_type](self, data)
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 343, in represent_object
    'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/object:'+function_name, state)
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 118, in represent_mapping
    node_value = self.represent_data(item_value)
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 52, in represent_data
    node = self.yaml_multi_representers[data_type](self, data)
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 343, in represent_object
    'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/object:'+function_name, state)
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 118, in represent_mapping
    node_value = self.represent_data(item_value)
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 52, in represent_data
    node = self.yaml_multi_representers[data_type](self, data)
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 346, in represent_object
    return self.represent_sequence(tag+function_name, args)
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 92, in represent_sequence
    node_item = self.represent_data(item)
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 48, in represent_data
    node = self.yaml_representers[data_types[0]](self, data)
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 286, in represent_tuple
    return self.represent_sequence('tag:yaml.org,2002:python/tuple', data)
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 92, in represent_sequence
    node_item = self.represent_data(item)
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 52, in represent_data
    node = self.yaml_multi_representers[data_type](self, data)
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 331, in represent_object
    if function.__name__ == '__newobj__':
AttributeError: 'functools.partial' object has no attribute '__name__'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As it stands, there is no way for others to figure out where the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ended up being caused by an issue with a recent pandas upgrade. Rolling back to 1.2.5 resolved the issue.

```
pip install --upgrade pandas==1.2.5
```

Details on the problem in the link below.

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/42748